# How could you specify an API that returned Observables?

Tags: websocket, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

An Observable - a collection over time - is a useful thing to be able to request over the web. A feed is best modeled as an Observable, not a static array that you must poll and diff to request.

My question - if I wanted to create a web endpoint that would let you do

```
web-tail -f http://somewhere.com/biz-quotes
```

This service, queried by a fictional utility `web-tail`, would every 5 seconds a new pithy business quote like "Custom departmental synergy" would be returned. I could write such a `web-tail` utility with WebSockets, and establish a convention for what field of emitted objects would be emitted to the console. But what language would I write a consumable specification in?

Is the Observable specification mature enough to be referenced?

Comment: consumable specification, you mean by how to write a client library using observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to write a client which consumes messages sent by a server over websockets, you can definitely use **RxJs** on top of, say, **socket.io**.

[This nice article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1?t=1&cn=ZmxleGlibGVfcmVjcw%3D%3D&refsrc=email&iid=9b197a27b4a14948b1d2fd4ad999e0a1&uid=39235406&nid=244%20276893704) explains you how this can work.

In a nutshell this is the TypeScript code you need.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs';

import * as socketIoClient from 'socket.io-client';

export class SocketObs {
    private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

    private connect = new Subject<any>();
    private disconnect = new Subject<any>();

    constructor(url: string);
    constructor(input: any) {
        this.socket = socketIoClient(input);
        this.socket.on('connect',
            () => {
                this.connect.next();
                // complete to make sure that this event is fired only once
                this.connect.complete();
            }
        );
        this.socket.on('disconnect',
            () => {
                this.disconnect.next();
                // complete to make sure that this event is fired only once
                this.disconnect.complete();
            }
        );

    }

    send(event, message?) {
        this.socket.emit(event, message);
    }
    onEvent(event): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<any>((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.socket.on(event, data => observer.next(data));
        });
    }
    onDisconnect() {
        return this.disconnect.asObservable();
    }
    onConnect() {
        return this.connect.asObservable();
    }

    close() {
        this.socket.close();
    }
}
```

SocketObs class offers you the API you need in form of Observable, in particular `onEvent` returns an Observable which emits any time a certain event is received from the server.

Comment: Great answer and link. Much obliged!